# Not able to login after updating android studio to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

So I updated my android studio from 2.2.3 to 2.3 and tried to run my app and since then I am not able to login to my apps parse back end. The exception is

```
com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value == null
```

this is the method from where this exception has been triggered.

```
public static void loginUser(String username, String password, final ParseLoginCallbacks callback) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loginUser: "+username);
    Log.d(TAG, "loginUser: "+password);
    final Integer num = 5;
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) { //user is null here with e = exception mentioned above. username and password has correct value.
            if (user != null) {
                // The user is logged in.

                    if (callback != null){
                        callback.loginSucceeded(user);
                        Log.d("myTag", "Log in succeded");
                    }
            }
            else {
                // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                if (callback != null)
                    callback.loginFailed(e);
                Log.d(TAG, "Parse user login failed");
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Same code I run in my collegues studio version 2.2.3 and its perfectly working fine. I am trying to see issues regarding new update 2.3 issues with parse but not able to find anything.

Any advices....????

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: hmmm, Isn't parse shut down ?

Answer (score 0):

IllegalArgumentException is thrown because you pass wrong argument to the function.[IAE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)

You should first reassure that your username or password is not null. Then pass it to the Parse if both variables are not null.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution for now. While initializing Parse I had to put an empty string for client key, before it was null... but still it makes me think that all these one year in the app it never caused any issue and with 2.3 android studio it does, but nevertheless now it works fine